# Better way of checking if number fall within a specific range, applying a function to each if they do not?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Both g1 an g2 are random integers.

I am calling a getValue() method on both which multiplies them by another integer.

I'm trying to check if the result of getvalue(g1) and getValue(g2) are greater than 20.

If they both equal to 0, and if they are less than 20, I apply another function to each of them.

Does anyone have a more concise way of doing this?

```
 def fitness(self):
      g1, g2 = self.select()

      if self.getValue(g1) > 20:
        g1 = 0 
      else:
        g1 = self.getBenifit(g1)

      if self.getValue(g2) > 20:
        g2 = 0 
      else:
        g2 = self.getBenifit(g2)

      return g1, g2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the `if` statements like this:

```
    g1 = 0 if self.getValue(g1) > 20 else self.getBenifit(g1)
    g2 = 0 if self.getValue(g2) > 20 else self.getBenifit(g2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As another answer points out, you can use syntax like this:

*value_if_true* `if` *condition* `else` *value_if_false*

Separately from that, you obviously have some repeated code here.  For only two items, it is probably not worth doing any differently, but if you get many more, you should consider making a function and calling it for each item.  Just to illustrate the point, you might end up with something like this:

```
def my_conversion(self, g):
    return 0 if self.getValue(g) > 20 else self.getBenifit(g)

def fitness(self):
    g1, g2 = self.select()
    return self.my_conversion(g1), self.my_conversion(g2)
```

Or if `self.select()` might return a large number of items, here is another possibility. In this case, maybe you don't need a separate function, but you do have a loop here instead.

```
def fitness(self):
    return tuple((0 if self.getValue(g) > 20 else self.getBenifit(g))
                  for g in self.select())
```

These are just options to bear in mind, and obviously I am *not* claiming that it clarifies the code in the case of only two items.